# Get argument char as ASCII code

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printf

I'm working on my school project "ROP on ARM vs x86"

i've done my work on x86 and trying 'ret2zp' on ARM right now and i need help.

please help such a linux newbie.

---

I'm following easy and neat example on ARM ['A Short Guid on ARM Exploitation' by Kumar & Gupta](http://www.exploit-db.com/wp-content/themes/exploit/docs/24493.pdf)

On page 41, (my reputation is lack to post img..sorry)
there is a line
 
(gdb) r 'printf "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD\x38\x84"
so Kumar & Gupta was trying to put char array AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD&„ (with extended ascii code. nothing on simple ascii code)

and i can't put my char array on argument for my code with 'printf' command;

here's my simple code to use 'printf'. 
buffer_overflow.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void IShouldNeverBeCalled(){
    puts("I should never be called");
    exit(0);
}

void Vulnerable(char *arg){
    char buff[10];
    strcpy(buff, arg);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Vulnerable(argv[1]);
    puts(argv[1]);
    return(0);
}
```

and it works as

```
root@linaro:~# ./buffer_overflow AAAABBBB
AAAABBBB

root@linaro:~# ./buffer_overflow 'printf "A"' 
printf "A"
```

so printf isn't working as i expected.

how can i use 'printf' as Kumar & Gupta said so??

how can my program get argument "A" when i put "'printf "\x41"'"?

and what is that printf? is it function on python something? or is it program integrated with ubuntu?

oh my ubuntu is

```
root@linaro:~# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu natty (development branch) \n \l
```

thank you for helping me .

Answer (score 0):

You're using apostrophe `'` instead of backtick `` ` ``. Additionally, the doc is missing the terminating backtick.

Instead of using backticks, though, you should use the better `$()` and quote properly:

```
./buffer_overflow "$(printf "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD\x38\x84")"
```

Also note that they're doing this in gdb, not in a shell.